# Using jQuery Datatables module for Drupal 7

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-7, datatables

I'm a Drupal newbie and have understood how to make my basic blocks and menus sofar. Also I've learned some jQuery (and it is awesome).

I'm trying to integrate a paginated list of users which is just [a separate PHP script](http://preferans.de/top20.php) at the moment into [my new Drupal 7 site](http://preferans.de):

[image]

I'm trying to implement it as a Drupal menu, so that I can call it like http://preferans.de/top (to have the pagination offset of 0) and http://preferans.de/top/100 (to display the list of users starting with the 100th user):

```
function pref_menu() {
  $items['top'] = array(
    'title' => 'Weekly player rating',
    'description' => 'Weekly player rating',
    'page callback' => 'pref_top_callback',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'file' => 'pref.top.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'pref'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

And my very simple pref.top.inc file is:

```
function pref_top_callback($offset = 0) {
  return array(
    'pref_players_table' => array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => pref_players_table($offset),
    ),
  );
}

function pref_fetch_players($offset) {
  /* FETCH MAX 20 RECORDS INTO AN ARRAY */
  $players = array();
  $result = db_query("
select u.id,
        u.first_name,
        row_number() OVER (order by m.money desc) as pos,
        u.female,
        u.city,
        u.avatar,
        m.money,
        u.login > u.logout as online
from pref_users u, pref_money m where
        m.yw=to_char(current_timestamp, 'IYYY-IW') and
        u.id=m.id
order by m.money desc
limit 20 offset :offset
", array(':offset' => array($offset)),
  array('fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
  );
  $players = $result->fetchAll();

  /* PRINT THE ARRAY AS AN HMTL-TABLE */
  $table = '<table>';
  foreach ($players as $user) {
    $table .= '<tr>';
    $table .= sprintf('<td>%u</td>
<td><a href="/user.php?id=%s">%s</a></td>
<td>%s</td><td>%d $</td>',
      $user['pos'],
      $user['id'],
      $user['first_name'],
      $user['city'],
      $user['money']);
    $table .= '</tr>';
  }

  $table .= '</table>';
  return $table;
}
```

This does work, I get a Drupal page with an HTML table containing up to 20 rows:

[image]

But I have no idea how to use [the Datatables Drupal module](http://drupal.org/project/datatables). I've downloaded and installed it successfully and am looking at its source code, but don't event know where to start.

Please help me, how can I call it from my menu function?

Thank you!
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That module is a Views plugin, you will need to expose your table to views to be able to use it.

Depending what you want, you can also get a sortable, multi-page table with just Drupal core, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-you-make-sortable-tables-with-a-pager-with-data-from-a-custom-table/367#367 on how you need to build your query to do that.

Some other hints on your code:

"$players = $result->fetchAll();" is unecessary. You can directly iterate over $result.

Also, you want to use theme('table'). Then, you just need this in your foreach hook:

```
<?php
$rows = array();
$header = array(t('Position'), t('Id'), t('First name'), t('City'), t('Money'));
foreach ($result as $player) {
  $rows[] = array($player['pos'], $player['id'], $player['first_name'], $player['city'], $player['money']);
}
return theme('table', array('rows' => $rows, 'header' => $header));
?>
```

Additionally, you will need to define the $header array, that is described in [theme_table()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) (see field and sort keys in $header).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your code: you populate the $rows array, but where do you pass/return it? And what is $header, can it be set to  $header = array('pos', 'id', 'first_name', 'city', 'money');  ?

Comment: I've also tried:   $header = array('pos', 'id', 'first_name', 'city', 'money');
  $rows = array();
  foreach ($players as $player) {
    $rows[] = array($player['pos'], $player['id'], $player['first_name'], $player['city'], $player['money']);
  }
return theme('table', $header, $rows);

but get a white screen with no table

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in there. Obviously, you need to pass $rows to 'rows'. I fixed it and also added an example for $header. Note that when you want to use TableSort, you need to extend $header, see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--dblog--dblog.admin.inc/function/dblog_overview/7 for an example.

Comment: What you had in your second comment is the D6 version, in D7, you pass an array of arguments as a single argument to theme instead of a number of arguments.